# Regex to check number is unique in list

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find a way to check whether the input string is the unique number or not. For example:

```
1,2,45,4,5 => true
11,13,14,15 => true
12,123,12,15 => false
3,5,67,3,5,3 => false
```

I had to learn and write the code `(\d+)(,|\d| )*(\1)` to test, but it failed in the same one-digit numbers, the failure case as:

```
23,13,14 
1,11,15
```

Comment: Can I ask why you chose regex as the tool to do this? If you're using [tag:C#] already, use C# to do this - not regex. If you're not using C#, please remove the tag.

Comment: @Rob I use regex to test string in C#

Comment: @taki In that case I'd highly recommend just using plain C#.. regex *probably can* do it, but it's not designed for that kind of thing

Comment: @GrantWinney I think regex is the best solution to check on the model file. Of course I could use javascript to check but I think it unprofessional manner. I have learned and seek to use regex to check the serial number on more than 4 hours but still no results.

Comment: @Rob thanks for your comment, Maybe I should not use regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You should check where the numbers end (the comas)

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(^|,)(\d+),(.*,)?\2($|,)");
```

**EDIT**

I made a bit more enigmatic version of the regex. It handles leading zeroes and spaces.

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(^|[,\s])0*(\d+)[,\s](.*[,\s])?0*\2($|[,\s])");
string[] samples = new string[]{
    "1,2,45,4,5",
    "11,13,14,15",
    "12,123,12,15",
    "3,5,67,3,5,3",
    "23,13,14",
    "1,11,15",
    "3,003",
    "1,3,4,3"
};

foreach (string sample in samples)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sample + " => " + (r.IsMatch(sample) ? "duplicit" : "unique"));
}
```

output

```
1,2,45,4,5 => unique
11,13,14,15 => unique
12,123,12,15 => duplicit
3,5,67,3,5,3 => duplicit
23,13,14 => unique
1,11,15 => unique
3,003 => duplicit
1,3,4,3 => duplicit
```

Comment: That old adage about having two problems. Definitely true here. Most people don't want to try to understand that regex.

Comment: It would be awesome if you showed usage on this regex with the examples provided. Also, it is a bit fragile if there is a space or leading 0s before the numbers.

Comment: I am very thankful for your answer, it was really great. But it fails in the case: 1,3,4,3

Comment: @taki I added two more samples, I do not see a problem with 1,3,4,3. Can You provide some code?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Sorry, your answer was correct. beacause I take it as a annotation like: `[Config("Regex", ErrorMessage = "Invalid AAA Values")]
 public string AAA{ get; set; }` Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

One way to detect duplicates, assuming you're open to non-regex solutions, is to split on the comma, group by number, and see if any numbers are repeated.

```
var input = "12,123,12,15";

var isUnique = input.Split(',')
                    .GroupBy(x => x)
                    .All(x => x.Count() == 1);  // returns false in this case
```

Comment: This doesn't treat multiple valid representations of the same number as equal ("003" vs "3"), and the question does ask about numbers. Of course, it's just as likely that the question is wrong and what you have presented here is what was wanted.

Comment: @moreON without that restriction explicitly mentioned, I don't think it's worth coding for. Parsing to int will fail if it's a decimal (a number), or if it's out of int range (still a number). Not to mention if it has a thousands separator (yup! a number). The list of edge cases is endless, really. Can't expect an answer to cover each one if they're not asked for by the OP.

Comment: @moreON why add requirements that are not part of the OP's question ?If you think this is of some value to the question at hand, then ask the OP in a comment if he wants that to be added as a requirement, but don't go commenting on answers based on your personal interpretation

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? (no regex)

```
public static bool func(string s){
    try {
        return s.Split(',')
        .Select(x=>Int32.Parse(x))
        .GroupBy(x=>x)
        .All(x=>x.Count() == 1)
    }catch (FormatException e){
        //oh noes the string was not formatted nicely :(
        return false; // do something appropriate for your application
    }
}
```